# passing a JavaScript array to PHP file returns empty array

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to pass a javascript array to PHP file like this:

Code in JS file:

```
let directories =JSON.stringify(["John", "Sara", "Max"]);   
$.post('../test.php', {directories: directories});
```

And inside the PHP file:

```
$directories = json_decode($_POST['directories']);
```

But each time I get an empty array! How can I fix this?

**Update**:

**PHP**

```
<?php
function getDirContents($directories, &$results = array()){

    $length = count($directories);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

    $files = array_diff(scandir($directories[$i]), array('..', '.'));;
    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = $directories[$i].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value;
        if(is_dir($path)) {
          getDirContents($path, $results);
        } else {
          $directory_path = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
          $results[] =  'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace($directory_path, "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .$path;
        }
    }

    }

    return $results;
}

$directories = json_decode($_POST['directories']);
print_r($_POST['directories'] 



echo json_encode(getDirContents($directories));
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready( function() {


    let directories =JSON.stringify(["recognition final tests", "4789"]);   
    $.post('../test.php', {directories: directories});

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../test.php',
            data: 'id=testdata',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            preload(result);

            },
        });
});




function preload(arr){
arr = arr.map(x => encodeURI(x));   
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global.Preload = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

    function preloadOne(url, done) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onprogress = event => {
            if (!event.lengthComputable) return false
            let item = this.getItemByUrl(event.target.responseURL);
            item.completion = parseInt((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            item.downloaded = event.loaded;
            item.total = event.total;
            this.updateProgressBar(item);
        };
        xhr.onload = event => {
            let type = event.target.response.type;
            let blob = new Blob([event.target.response], { type: type });
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let responseURL = event.target.responseURL;
            let item = this.getItemByUrl(responseURL);
            item.blobUrl = url;
            item.fileName = responseURL.substring(responseURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            item.type = type;
            item.size = blob.size;
            done(item);
        };

        xhr.onerror = event => {
        console.log('an error happed herrt')
    };

        xhr.send();
    }

    function updateProgressBar(item) {
        var sumCompletion = 0;
        var maxCompletion = this.status.length * 100;

        for (var itemStatus of this.status) {
            if (itemStatus.completion) {
                sumCompletion += itemStatus.completion;
            }
        }
        var totalCompletion = parseInt((sumCompletion / maxCompletion) * 100);

        if (!isNaN(totalCompletion)) {
            this.onprogress({
                progress: totalCompletion,
                item: item
            });
        }
    }

    function getItemByUrl(rawUrl) {
        for (var item of this.status) {
            if (item.url == rawUrl) return item
        }
    }

    function fetch(list) {  
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.loaded = list.length;
            for (let item of list) {
                this.status.push({ url: item });
                this.preloadOne(item, item => {
                    this.onfetched(item);
                    this.loaded--;
                    if (this.loaded == 0) {
                        this.oncomplete(this.status);
                        resolve(this.status);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    }

    function Preload() {
        return {
            status: [],
            loaded: false,
            onprogress: () => {},
            oncomplete: () => {},
            onfetched: () => {},
            fetch,
            updateProgressBar,
            preloadOne,
            getItemByUrl
        }
    }

    return Preload;

})));


const preload = Preload();

preload.fetch(arr).then(items => {
  // use either a promise or 'oncomplete'
  console.log(items);
});

preload.oncomplete = items => {
  console.log(items);
}

preload.onprogress = event => {
  console.log(event.progress + '%');
}

preload.onfetched = item => {
  console.log(item);
}

};
```

**UPDATE 2:**

JS

```
$(document).ready( function() {


    let directories =JSON.stringify(["recognition final tests", "4789"]);   
    //$.post('../test.php', {directories: directories});

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../test.php',
            data: {directories: directories , id : "testdata"} ,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            preload(result);

            },
        });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$directories = json_decode($_POST['directories']);
print_r($_POST['directories']
```

Still I get `jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST https://reed123.000webhostapp.com/test.php 500`

Comment: What shows with print_r($_POST['directories']

Comment: Use the json_last_error function in order to get the idea that what may be wrong with the json

Comment: Your php code is right. please tell us what do you see on your console

Comment: I get an empty array in console... I update the question and add the full code...

Comment: Try to print $_POST

Comment: jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST https://reed123.000webhostapp.com/test.php 500

Comment: please close you parentese in your php code

Comment: I've closed that parentese and it fixed the error but still, I can't see the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try print your response with print_r($_POST)

You will see you don't send {directories: directories} in your request's body and in your php you try get  data:  $_POST['directories'] so you get a response with server error (500 status)

**Updated:**

And it's better if you send just one request and send all data with that

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../test.php',
        data:  {directories: directories , id : "testdata"},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            preload(result);

        },
    });
});
```

and in your php code:

```
print_r($_POST['directories']) ;
```

You haven't closed the prantese :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer...plus one but I need the second request too... How can I use them at the same time?

Comment: both your requests try to send to a same address. so you can send a request with a data like {directories: directories , id : "testdata"}

Comment: Please have a look at update 2... I can't make your solution work...

Comment: I updated my anwer. if you dont get your answer please make comment. I 'll update my answer again. Thank you

Comment: print_r($_POST['directories'] 

این رو میگم. پرانتز رو نبستی خب

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210690/discussion-between-ali-sharifineyestani-and-foxer).

Comment: id : "testdata" به هیچ چیزی در سمت سرور متصل نیست

Comment: console.log(result); داره مقادیر دایرکتوریز رو لاگ می کنه که می خواستیم به سرور بفرستیم و چیزی در سمت سرور پرینت نمی شه اصلا

Comment: بیا توی دیسکاشن استک تا راهنماییت کنم. داریم کامنت رو فارسی شلوغ می کنیم خلاف قوانینه. ببین این مقدار رو من از روی کد خودت برداشتم. خب دقیقا میخوای چیکار کنی؟؟الان من کدت رو توی مرورگر خودم تست کردم کاملا درست کار میکنه. من نمیدونم اون مقدار چیه

Comment: بهترین روش اینه شما بری توی ابزار توسعه ی گوگل
توی تب نتورک
ازونجا ریسپانس رو برام بفرستی تا بگم مشکل کجاست. در هر صورت کدت درسته من الان تست کردم کامل داره کار میکنه